# FullCalendar and Google Calendar wont show event name

Tags: javascript, google-api, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Followed the Fullcalendar documentation and came up with this code:

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDDHAjgjLggGtS0KChhDLzwej1U6NJmGvU',
            events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user%40mail.com/public/basic' ,
        });
```

And shows something like this:

[image: How its showing]

Events with no title are Google Calendar events. The other events are created manually.

The problem is that Events incoming from Google Calendar are just coming without any data, just the timestamp.

The calendar is public, accessed it from incognito window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in a my company domain administration panel i have to enable the public sharing of my calendar.

I am still not sure if this is convenient because i want only users that are logged into their Google account to see their own calendar through my fullcalendar implementation.

Comment: Use a service account for access give the service account access to the calendar then it doesn't need to be set public. (Note: service account wont work with JavaScript you need to use a service sided languge)